# How to send forms via fax?

Tags: fax

I have never done this. I have signed forms, I scanned them. Now I need to send the forms via fax.

How do I this?

Comment: Are you using a fax machine or are you trying to send a fax directly from your computer? What software are you using to try to send the fax? We need a little more info here...

Comment: What Operating System are you using?

Comment: Ask your secretary, or your boss's secretary if you don't have one. (unless you are the secretary)

Answer (score 1):

If the fax is installed on your PC and you are using windows:-

Open the document, select File >> Print and then in the drop-down box, where it currently shows your printer, select your fax and press OK.

Answer (score 0):

In windows Xp and above you can search in the start menu under accessories, for a Fax manager. It's a very simple software that comes with windows. You'll need a regular old modem to use it.
If you can't find it, You'll have to go to control panel->add of remove software-> windows components, and install it.

I have to say that Fax is something ancient... you should try scanning and sending an e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow this link, there are free internet fax services. One of these should help you.

http://www.google.ca/search?q=free+fax+service&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a

Regards,

Comment: Not even a helpful answer